# MySQL Error 1064 with single Column Table

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I am developing with Laravel/Homestead and I use MySQL as my database. For test purposes, I tried to insert data to test my relationships (yes, you can use seeders for this, but it was too complex writing it for the scale of my database).

All of my Inserts worked, except for one. The Table 'Character' throws an error 1064 (42000), when I try to insert. This table has only two columns: a characterId and a name (String).

The detailed exception message is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Character(name) VALUES("Random name")' at line 1

My insert looks like this:  `` INSERT INTO Character(`name`) VALUES("James Brafferson"); ``

I already tried to rename the column name to characterName, that didn't work either. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Character(`name`) VALUES("Random name")' at line 1

Comment: You should have tried renaming the table, not the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Character** is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-C) in MySQL. You can add the **`** symbol to escape it.

Can you please try the below query:

```
INSERT INTO `Character` (`name`) VALUES ("James Brafferson");
```

or you may rename the table name, which is not in the [keyword or reserved word list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Ah yeah, that works, thanks! Didn't know that Character is reserved as well